# Use SemaphoreSlim when generating array of tasks in LINQ lambda expression

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq

I am using a LINQ lambda expression to generate an array of tasks and add them to a list of tasks. I want to implement a Semaphore to limit the number of tasks in process at a given point in time.

Here is code that represents what I currently have:

```cs
class Test {
    private List<Task> tasks;

    public void Start(){
        tasks = new List<Task>();
        AddTasks();
    }

    private void AddTasks(){
        tasks.AddRange(
            items
            .Where(x => x.InProcess == false)
            .Select( async (item) = > {
                await DoWork(item);
            })
            .ToArray()
        );
    }
}
```

I want to achieve something similar to:

```cs
class Test {
    private List<Task> tasks;
    private SemaphoreSlim semaphore ;

    public void Start(){
        tasks = new List<Task>();
        semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5);
        AddTasks();
    }

    private void AddTasks(){
        tasks.AddRange(
            items
            .Where(x => x.InProcess == false)
            .Select( async (item) = > {
                await semaphore.AwaitAsync();
                try
                {
                    await DoWork(item);
                }
                catch (System.Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
                finally {
                    semaphore.Release();
                }
            })
            .ToArray()
        );
    }
}
```

But I do not think this will work correctly, as the semaphore is inside of the task. How can I use the semaphore as part of the LINQ query to stall generating new tasks until the semaphore is awaited?

Comment: What's you're final goal here?

Comment: @stuartd `Parallel.ForEach` is for synchronous CPU bound operations, not asynchronous operations.

Comment: I've considered Parallel.ForEach but my actual work is heavy I/O with little CPU work (plus what @Servy said). I originally started with Task.Run to generate tasks but found this way to be cleaner. It is possible that the list of items could be in the hundreds, so I want to limit the # of tasks being generated so that I don't starve any threads.

Comment: If you want to know if the code will work correctly *try it*, and see if it works correctly.  Whether or not it does, and what happens when it runs, will help you figure out where you need to go from here.

Comment: `so that I don't starve any threads` - usually, you can just trust the thread pool to do the right thing. A few hundred tasks is not a lot, especially if they're asynchronous I/O-based tasks. I'd try it *without* throttling first and see if that's good. If you want to do it *with* throttling, the code you have is correct.

Comment: It's pointless to catch exceptions only to always rethrow them without doing anything else.  Just remove the `catch` clause.

Comment: @StephenCleary, thanks for the tip. I have had some throttling issues which I why I am looking at this. I am glad to know what I have is correct then.

Comment: @Servy I know, this was just example code. My real code is significantly more complex so I simplified the process for this question. In reality, other things happen when an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code. It should work as you expected but I haven't tried it. And don't forget to call `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` when it's done and you need to get result.

```
private void AddTasks()
    {
        tasks.AddRange(items
                       .Where(x => x.InProcess == false)
                       .Select(AddTaskAsync)
                       .ToArray());

        //later await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private async Task AddTaskAsync(YourClass item)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            await DoWork(item);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The name `AddTaskAsync` is a bit misleading, because the created task in not added somewhere. A better name for the method could be `DoWorkAsync`.

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias a lot! It's so important to have the right names! Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score -1):

My example code did accomplish what I intended. Using the semaphore inside of the Task didn't cause any problems. It prevented the Task from running, which was the goal.